# Making a general search box using php and mysql to search through several tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables namely: `tbl_subscriber` and `tbl_faculty`.
 
`tbl_subscriber` has fields namely:`name`,`id_number`,`email`,`phone`.
`tbl_faculty` has :`f_name`,`l_name`,`email`,`phone`.

I have a search box. I want to write a query that if I type a phone number / email / name / f_name / l_name in it then it should search both the tables to match the supplied entry and it should return all rows corresponding to that entry.

It is for sure that the supplied entry would be in either of the mentioned table (as I have made the tables like that)and not in both. What I mean is at one time only one table fields would match but the query should search both the tables simultaneously.

Comment: i have tried using case and union all.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question, and explain exactly what the problem is that you're getting?

Comment: select * from tbl_subscriber union all select * from tbl_faculty - the query gives " The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: i cannot use the case in this as i have more than 1000 subscribers and faculty members in the respective tables

Comment: Please edit your question with your SQL query and the structure of your tables. You can't use a UNION if the tables have different layouts.

Comment: I've described my query precisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select x , y  from tbl_subscriber 
  union all 
  select x , null as y  from tbl_faculty
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT name,id_number,email,phone FROM tbl_subscriber
UNION 
SELECT CONCAT(f_name, ' ', l_name) AS name, id_number, email, phone FROM tbl_faculty
```

You might need to do some casting for the name field, but it does at least get around the problem of the tables having different number of fields.